# Find all the documents in a collection using MongoManager class in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to get data from all documents that are in `Collection`. In my case the data is `Color` field. I want to retrieve all the `Color` fields values from all documents that are in the `Collection`. Is it possible using `MongoManager` class in `PHP`? I am trying in this way;

```
 $mng = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query([]);     
    $r = $mng->executeQuery("DB.Collection", $query);
    $R = current($r->toArray());

    if (!empty($R)) {
        echo ($R->Color);
    } else {
        echo "Nothing found";
    }
```

But it gives only one field. How can I get all color fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use distinct to get `color` field values from collection.

```
$mng = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$cmd = new MongoDB\Driver\Command([
    'distinct' => Collection,
    'key' => 'color'
]);
$cursor = $mng->executeCommand(DB, $cmd);
$color = current($cursor->toArray())->values;
```

Comment: If i want to find all field data from all documents. Not specific to `color`. Then? As my question heading says "Find all the documents in a collection"

Comment: you just do a normal find to get all data

Comment: My collection has multiple documents and each document has color, link, back,submit,shape fields. I want all fields data from all documents.

Comment: Something like this `$cursor = $mng ->executeQuery('DB.Collection', $query);
foreach ($cursor as $document) {
    var_dump($document);
}`